# interpreting "nirguna" as "no inauspicious qualities"

Tags: brahman, ramanujacharya, nirguna

I believe Ramanuja reconciles Nirguna Brahman with a personal God by interpreting "nirguna" as "no bad qualities." or "no inauspicious qualities".

But do we know what is good or bad in absolute terms?

if you take everyday dualities like

short tall

slim fat

asleep awake

happy sad

hot cold

laugh cry

wet dry

it is not clear they can all be classified as "good" (Kalyana) or ""bad".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Good/Bad classification of physical attributes is only a perspective from the point of view of jIvas. Not from an absolute point of view. E.g. what is fragrant to a pig or a fly may be an odour to a human.

However there are other attributes such as cruelty, partiality which can be considered absolutely bad. They cannot be considered good from any perspective. It is such qualities that the Sruti says that Brahman is devoid of.

- E.g the Chandogya Upanishad describes the Brahman as apahatapApmA - free from evil.
- The Brahmasutras describe Brahmans as one devoid of cruelty or partiality.

Comment: good/bad, sin/good deed all involve ambiguity.  Krishna himself says the great kaurava  heroes could not have been killed without adharma @hashable  He might say the adharma allowed dharma to prevail from another viewpoint.  But duality is always a limited/limiting concept.

Comment: @SK - it's not that hard to comprehend. a surgeon cuts a patient's body to remove a tumor. Is the tumor violent ? yes, it causes harm to the patient. is the surgeon's cut violent ? yes, it causes the patient to bleed. is one violence opposite and less than the other violence ? yes. You are living under the false assumption that there is a good and a bad. No, there is a smaller good, and a bigger good (or a smaller bad and a bigger bad). What matters is the resultant evaluation of the formula, if after adding subtracting good and bad, what's left is good, then - ends justify means.

Answer (score 1):

You have conflated human perceptions/frailities (which are the result of human birth and all human birth results in suffering) with divine 'qualities'. In his *Sri-Bhasya* on the *Brahma Sutras*, Sri Ramanuja's verse and commentary on 3.2.11 reads (*Brahma Sutras According to Sri Ramanuja*, Swamis Vireshwarananda and Adidevananda translators):

> 11. **Not even on account of place (is there any imperfection) in Brahman, because throughout (the scripture It is described) as having a twofold characteristic.**
>
> The supreme Brahman is not contaminated by imperfections like the soul, though it abides in the earth, the soul, etc. as their inner ruler. Why? Because throughout the scripture, Brahman is described as having a two-fold nature, viz. being free from all imperfections and as possessing all blessed qualities. 'This is the Atman, free from evil, free from old age, free from death, free from sorrow...whose desire is True, whose resolve is True' (*Chandogya U*. VIII.i.5); 'Who is omniscient in general and all-knowing in detail' (*Mundakya U*. I.i.9); 'Without any stain etc.' (*Svetasvatara U.* VI.19); 'His nature is full of all blessed qualities...where all evils, sufferings, etc. do not exist' (*Visnu Purana* VI.v.84-85).

Comment: not an answer.  "evil" is an undefined concept.  who was 'evil" in the Mahabharata?  Was the summary execuation of Sambuka engaed in tapas evil? old age is just a quality.  it brings wisdom.  "kalyana gunas" is useless to further spiritual inquiry @swamivishwananda

Comment: your argument in your comment is with Sri Ramanuja, the commentary is Sri Ramanuja's not mine.

Comment: why cite something if you can't defend it?  I don't accept argument from authority. @swamivishwananda

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. Your objection is a good one. We don't know what is good or bad in absolute terms. The concept of the Personal God is only valid in the relative world.

Sri Ramanuja's attempt fails on another ground. No one knows the true nature of Brahman.

Brahman is the Ultimate Reality. It’s nature is not grasped by the human intellect. It is also called Sat-chid-anand (Existence-knowledge-bliss).

> Manu said, ‘**Brahman is not an object of touch, or of hearing, or of
> taste, or of sight, or of smell, or of any deductive inference from
> the Known.** Only the Understanding (when withdrawn from everything
> else) can attain to it. All objects that the mind apprehends through
> the senses are capable of being withdrawn into the mind; the mind can
> be withdrawn into the understanding; the Understanding can be
> withdrawn into the soul, and the Soul into the Supreme.’

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCIV**

**Brahman according to Yajnavalkya**

> Yajnavalkya said: O Gargi, it is the supreme being that the non-yogins
> call gross but, in fact, that is eternal and wonderful lord; one that
> is not long, not red, that has no head, that has no setting, hence
> that has a lasting taste, that has no contact, no smell, no juice, no
> eyes, no ears, neither speech nor mind, no brilliance, no proof [or
> magnitude], no (worldly) happiness, no name, no race, no death, no
> age, no ailment; that is nectarine, that is expressed by the word Om,
> that is immortal, that has neither a predecessor nor a successor, that
> is endless and non-external. It eats something. It does not eat
> anything. ..

**Linga Purana II.9.53–54**

> Príthiví (Earth).--Hail to thee, who art all creatures; to thee, the
> holder of the mace and shell: elevate me now from this place, as thou
> hast upraised me in days of old. From thee have I proceeded; of thee
> do I consist; as do the skies, and all other existing things. Hail to
> thee, spirit of the supreme spirit; to thee, soul of soul; to thee,
> who art discrete and indiscrete matter; who art one with the elements
> and with time. Thou art the creator of all things, their preserver,
> and their destroyer, in the forms, oh lord, of Brahmá, Vishńu, and
> Rudra, at the seasons of creation, duration, and dissolution. When
> thou hast devoured all things, thou reposest on the ocean that sweeps
> over the world, meditated upon, oh Govinda, by the wise. **No one
> knoweth thy true nature, and the gods adore thee only in the forms it
> hath pleased thee to assume.** They who are desirous of final
> liberation, worship thee as the supreme Brahmán; and who that adores
> not Vásudeva, shall obtain emancipation? Whatever may be apprehended
> by the mind, whatever may be perceived by the senses, whatever may he
> discerned by the intellect, all is but a form of thee. I am of thee,
> upheld by thee; thou art my creator, and to thee I fly for refuge:
> hence, in this universe, Mádhaví (the bride of Mádhava or Vishńu) is
> my designation. Triumph to the essence of all wisdom, to the
> unchangeable, the imperishable: triumph to the eternal; to the
> indiscrete, to the essence of discrete things: to him who is both
> cause and effect; who is the universe; the sinless lord of sacrifice
> 4; triumph. Thou art sacrifice; thou art the oblation; thou art the
> mystic Omkára; thou art the sacrificial fires; thou art the Vedas, and
> their dependent sciences; thou art, Hari, the object of all worship 5.
> The sun, the stars, the planets, the whole world; all that is
> formless, or that has form; all that is visible, or invisible; all,
> Purushottama, that I have said, or left unsaid; all this, Supreme,
> thou art. Hail to thee, again and again! hail! all hail!

**Vishnu Purana I.4**